# Group members must request access to access Group Files?

Tags: permissions, groups, access, site-settings

I created an Office 365 Group/Site on our companies enterprise account. I then added 4 people from within our organization to the group.

They got e-mailed the typical "Welcome to Group X" email.  They clicked on "Edit and Share files" link from within the e-mail and were brought to the group in their browser.  When they clicked "Browse Library", they were met with a "You must request access to view these files".

My question is, I thought Group members were already supposed to have view/edit access, why are they are having to request access again as if they were not already in the group?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you found "Something went wrong..." in creating the group. The whole point of Office 365 groups is that adding users to the group as members instantly give the access to the sites resources, including files in the document library.

> You don’t have to worry about manually assigning permissions to all
>   those resources because adding members to the group automatically
>   gives them the permissions they need to the tools your group provides.

Ref: [Learn about Office 365 groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

You can always check permission going to Settings (gear icon) > Site Permission > Advanced permission setting and see what kind of permission each group has (owner, member and visitor) and verify that users are in the members group.

Still doesn't work - delete the group, and create a new one.